# Ignore case in selector rvest

Tags: r, rvest

In javascript, the following selector with ignore case works

```
document.querySelectorAll("[class*='classA' i],[class*='classF' i]");
```

But in `rvest`, using the following

```r
html %>% html_nodes('[class*="classA" i],[class*="classF" i]') %>%  html_text()
```

gives me the following error:

> Error in parse_attrib(result, stream) :    Expected ']', got < IDENT
>   'i' at 19>

It works perfectly without the `i` inside the selector isn't mentioned, I don't want to write extra code to get all nodes ignoring case.

Is there any easier way to get nodes with class selectors that ignore case with `rvest`?

Comment: I _think_ (maybe someone can confirm) that case-insensitive selectors are only found in CSS4, and `rvest` uses CSS3.

Comment: @neilfws you're [right](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rvest/versions/0.3.4/topics/html_nodes). For now I'm using the xpath (still too long), thanks